# Difference between $(this).src and document.getElementById().src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a current project I am using jQuery. I was just wondering why this works,

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function(){
    document.getElementById('homeIcon').src = "pic/home-icon_hover.png";
})
```

but this won't:

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function(){
    $(this).src = "pic/home-icon_hover.png";
})
```

Shouldn't those methods do exactly the same?

FYI `homeIcon` is an `<img>`.

Comment: just do this instead: `this.src = "pic/home-icon_hover.png"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jquery you should do

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src',"pic/home-icon_hover.png")
})
```

To set the value of the src attribute. from jQuery version 1.6 and up it is recommended to use prop instead of attr, so:

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function() {
    $(this).prop('src',"pic/home-icon_hover.png")
})
```

Comment: It is recommended to start using `.prop` instead

Comment: Well, this was the explanation I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Correct but he didn't mention what jQuery version he is using so I played it safe. Moreover, I don't think there is a difference with the src attribute, but I agree it's the correct way to go

Comment: It's also important to remember that `$(this)` doesn't return the DOM element itself, but rather a jQuery object that represents it. See my answer for more info.

Comment: Even more recommended (by me, and others) is to use neither `prop()` nor `attr()` for this and just use the DOM `src` property. It's faster, clearer and more reliable.

Comment: SO JavaScript regular Andy E makes this point well: http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element

Answer (score 2):

since the getElementById() returns the actual HTML object, that has .src as a property.

whereas $("#dxx") returns a JQuery object - that can be accessed as an array - so you could use $("#dxx")[0].src (in case there's at least one item) and that would work the same

Comment: `$('#dxx')` actually returns a jQuery object, which can be used like an array, but it's not actually an array.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` returns a jQuery object that represents the DOM element, but not the DOM element itself.

You need to use `.attr()` to set the attribute.

```
$(this).attr("src", "pic/home-icon_hover.png");
```

See this for more info: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

There's a very nice explanation over at Remy Sharp's blog: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: `prop()` and `attr()` are unnecessary. Just use the DOM `src` property of `this`. Nitpick: the page you linked to is written by a guy called Remy Sharp rather than being a page on a weirdly-named site.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', "pic/home-icon_hover.png");
})
```

Comment: That won't work actually, $(this).attr('src') returns the value

Comment: @idanzalz yes that was a typo, sorry i already corrected that!

Answer (score 0):

When you extend the JS object to a jQuery one you should set attributes using the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', "pic/home-icon_hover.png");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` results in a jQuery object. If you want to change the `src` attribute you have to do

```
$(this).attr("src", "icon.png");
// or from version 1.6
$(this).prop("src", "icon.png");
```

see [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [jQuery prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

to use the `.src` attribute on a jQuery object you can return the DOM element by doing

```
$(this).get(0).src = 'icon.png';
```

see [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: `.get()` returns an array, you might mean `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you wrap your object (`this`) in jQuery you then have an Array of elements, try printing it out to the console:

```
console.log($(this)); // [ img ]
```

To expand on the correct answer provided by @idanzalz; if you do:

```
$(this).attr("src", "xyz");
```

The `src` attribute will be changed **on all matched elements**. In this case the only matched element is `this`.

Answer (score 0):

For setting a property of a single element, don't bother with either `attr()` or `prop()`. jQuery conveniently provides you with a reference to the element you want, so use it:

```
$('#homeIcon').hover(function() {
    this.src = "pic/home-icon_hover.png";
})
```